# lodash groupBy condition on params

Tags: lodash

I'm trying to convert this with lodash..... or maybe ES7

```
[
  {
    "name":"Rue Pierre",
    "details":{
      "name":"Rue Pierre"
    }
  },
  {
    "name":"Rue de Wavrin",
    "details":{
      "ref":"D 241",
      "name":"Rue de Wavrin"
    }
  },
  {
    "name":"Rue de paris",
    "details":{
      "ref":"D 241",
      "name":"Rue de paris"
    }
  }
]
```

in

```
{
  "Rue Pierre": [
    { "name": "Rue Pierre", "details": { "name": "Rue Pierre Gilles de Gennes" }}
  ],
   "D 241': [
     {"name": "Rue de paris", "details": {"ref": "D 241", "name": "Rue de paris"}},
     {"name": "Rue de Wavrin", "details": { "ref": "D 241", "name": "Rue de Wavrin" }}
    ]
}
```

If the property 'ref" exist i groupBy "ref" else groupBy "name".
It's possible in one step?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

[`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy) accepts a predicate. In the predicate you can use [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get) to get the value of a path ('details.ref') from the object, and if the value is undefined use a default value (`o.name`) instead.

```js
const data = [{"name":"Rue Pierre","details":{"name":"Rue Pierre"}},{"name":"Rue de Wavrin","details":{"ref":"D 241","name":"Rue de Wavrin"}},{"name":"Rue de paris","details":{"ref":"D 241","name":"Rue de paris"}}];

const result = _.groupBy(data, (o) => _.get(o, 'details.ref', o.name));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```